# In Windows 7's "XP Mode", do you have to click shift the focus to the "XP" Window?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

In the current Virtual PC when you click on an app in VPC, you have to click twice: once to get the focus on the Virtual PC window and again to click on a program in the VPC guest.

Does it work the same way in Windows XP Mode in Win 7?

***Windows XP Mode.*** Formerly called Virtual Windows XP (VXP), this solution provides users with the ability to run many older Windows XP applications in a virtual Windows XP environment, side-by-side with native Windows 7 applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Windows XP mode runs in "seamless" mode. The application shows up in the taskbar just like any other program, allowing you to easily switch back and forth.

There's an [excellent video at TechRepublic](http://video.techrepublic.com.com/2422-13792_11-346621.html) showing Excel 2003 on the VPC and Excel 2007 on the host running side-by-side.

From the [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2009/10/15/AR2009101503137.html) (weird place to get tech details, but they're right!):

> Where XP Mode really shines is with
>   Seamless Mode, which lets you launch
>   XP apps straight from your Windows 7
>   menus. To use Seamless Mode, you first
>   install an app under Desktop Mode,
>   then log out of and close the virtual
>   machine. The app you just installed
>   can then be found on the host PC's
>   Start menu under All Programs, Windows
>   Virtual PC, Windows XP Mode
>   Applications.
>
> When the app is launched from the host
>   OS, XP launches in the background and
>   the app appears as if it were running
>   natively in Windows 7. Apps run this
>   way are called virtual applications.
>   If you don't find the default start
>   menu location to be convenient, you
>   can move the shortcut to any location
>   a traditional shortcut can be placed.
>   If the app you want to virtualize
>   doesn't automatically create a Start
>   menu shortcut, or the app is already
>   included with Windows (Internet
>   Explorer 6.0 for example), you simply
>   need to create a shortcut for it in
>   Desktop Mode under c:\documents and
>   settings\all users\start menu and the
>   app will appear on the host start menu
>   under Windows XP Mode Applications.
>
> Seamless Mode isn't completely
>   seamless; there are couple issues with
>   it. In multi-monitor setups, the
>   virtual application only lives on the
>   primary monitor. Also, virtual apps
>   don't want to play along with the
>   Windows 7 Snap feature. Their Windows
>   needed to be manually resized. It's
>   also important to note that virtual
>   applications and Desktop Mode cannot
>   be used simultaneously. Finally,
>   you'll need to keep in mind that a
>   full OS needs to boot before a virtual
>   app can be run, so a little patience
>   will be needed on that first launch.